# Get previous search using AJAX codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am currently developing an airline system. The modules that I've done are: The search for available flights, login and register. In my search, the fields that I've are: 2 radio buttons(One way and round trip); 2 dropdown list(Origin and destination); 2 datepicker(if you chose round trip,the return and depart date); if you chose one way, the return field will be hidden.

After filling up these fields, all the available flight will be shown and there will be a button "select flight" but I put some validation that user must login first before they can select the flight.

NOTE: The things that I have done for my validation in login, first I need to check if both fields(username and password) have a value; Second if username and password is matched, if yes then all the basic information of that account will save into one variable; Third, check if the account is verified or not, if yes all the information will be save using the session.

And also, I only tried  echo "< script>" in my controller this is where the prompt message will be display. After showing the prompt message, all the available flight will give me now an error $flight_from, $flight_to and so on.

Example:

(o) One way (x) Round trip(chose this)

From: Country 1

To: Country 2

Depart: June 22, 2017

Return: July 19,2017

No of Passengers: 2 then clicked search

*Now, all the available flights will be display that has a select flight button*

Then when I click the select flight, there will be a message prompt that you must login then it will redirect you into Users/search

But the problem is after redirect it will give me an error $flight_from etc.

Question: So question is, after showing the prompt message I want to display all the available flights that user searched using AJAX.

**Controller**

// The method after the user clicked the select flight

```
public function search()
{
    $data['countries'] = $this->CrudModel->get('countries');
    $flight_type = $_POST['flight_type'];
    $pass_num = $_POST['no_of_passengers'];
    $testing = $this->session->set_userdata('pass_num',$pass_num);

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="padding:0px;" >', '</div>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_from', 'Select depature', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_to', 'Select Destination', 'required|trim');

    if ($flight_type == 'round_trip')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('return', 'Date of return', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_passengers', 'Number of Passengers', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();

        }
        else
        {
            $search_result = array(
                $flight_from = $_POST['flight_from'],
                $flight_to = $_POST['flight_to'],
                $depart = $_POST['depart'],
                $return = $_POST['return'],
                $no_of_passengers = $_POST['no_of_passengers']
            );
            $data['search_result'] = $this->CrudModel->search_round_trip('flight',$flight_from,$flight_to,$depart,$return,$no_of_passengers);
            $this->session->tempdata($data['search_result']);
            $this->session->tempdata();
            $this->load->view('partials/header');
            $this->load->view('partials/nav');
            $this->load->view('result',$data);
        } 

    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_passengers', 'Number of Passengers', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();

        }
        else {
            $search_result = array(
                $flight_from = $_POST['flight_from'],
                $flight_to = $_POST['flight_to'],
                $depart = $_POST['depart'],
                $no_of_passengers = $_POST['no_of_passengers']
            );
        $data['search_result'] = $this->CrudModel->search_one_way('flight',$flight_from,$flight_to,$depart,$no_of_passengers);

        $this->load->view('partials/header');
        $this->load->view('partials/nav');
        $this->load->view('result',$data);
        }

    }
}
public function selected_flight()
        {
            $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            if($this->session->userdata('user') != true)
            {

                echo "<script>
                    window.alert('You need to login first!');
                    location.href = '".site_url('User/search')."';
                    </script>";

            }
            else
            {
                $data['getFlight'] = $this->CrudModel->get_where('flight','flight_id',$id);
                $this->load->view('partials/header');
                $this->load->view('partials/nav');
                $this->load->view('confirmation',$data);
            }


        }
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach($search_result as $result):?>
            <div class="pure-u-1-1 resultborder">
               <img src="<?= base_url().'assets/images/aa.gif'?>" class="fleft">
               <table class="ml100">
                  <tr>
                     <th>Flight number <?= $result->flight_number?></th>
                     <th>operated by: <?= $result->operated_by?></th>
                     <th><?= date('h:ia',strtotime($result->flight_time))?> - <?= date("l F j, Y",strtotime($result->flight_depart))?></th>
                     <th><?= $result->flight_from?></th>
                     <th>Seat Availability:<?= $result->seat_availability?></th>

                     <th><a href="<?= base_url(). 'User/selected_flight/'.$result->flight_id?>"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> Select Flight</button></a></th>
                  </tr>

               </table>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: imho if you want to save such data - you should use the localstorage

Comment: What do you mean localstorage

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter supports `“tempdata”`, or session data with a specific expiration time. After the value expires, or the session expires or is deleted, the value is automatically removed.

Similarly to flashdata, tempdata variables are regular session vars that are marked in a specific way under the ‘__ci_vars’ key (again, don’t touch that one).

You can set and get tempdata value from session, Please find below mentioned solution.

```
// Set Temp Data    
$this->session->set_tempdata('item', 'value', 300); // Expire in 5 minutes

// Retrieve Specific Tempdata
$this->session->tempdata('item');

// Retrieve all Tempdata 
$this->session->tempdata();
```

This will help you.

Please find below mentioned solution.

In Controller

```
if($this->session->userdata('user') != true){
    // HERE you have to insert search params in TempData
    $this->session->set_tempdata('search_param', $this->input->post(), 300);
}

public function search(){ 
   if($this->session->tempdata('search_param') !== NULL):
       // assign values $flight_type, $pass_num etc
       // set post data for form validation
       $this->form_validation->set_data($this->session->tempdata('search_param'));

       YOUR CODE

       // Unset Tempdata after this
       $this->session->unset_tempdata('search_param');
   endif;
}
```

Your `search()` function will look like this.

```
public function search() {
    $data['countries'] = $this->CrudModel->get('countries');
    if ($this->session->tempdata('search_param') !== NULL):
        $prevSearchData = $this->session->tempdata('search_param');
        $flight_type = $prevSearchData['flight_type'];
        $pass_num = $prevSearchData['no_of_passengers'];
        $this->form_validation->set_data($prevSearchData);
    else:
        $flight_type = $_POST['flight_type'];
        $pass_num = $_POST['no_of_passengers'];
    endif;

    $testing = $this->session->set_userdata('pass_num', $pass_num);
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="padding:0px;" >', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_from', 'Select depature', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_to', 'Select Destination', 'required|trim');
    if ($flight_type == 'round_trip') {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('return', 'Date of return', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_passengers', 'Number of Passengers', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->index();
        } else {
            $search_result = array(
                $flight_from = $_POST['flight_from'],
                $flight_to = $_POST['flight_to'],
                $depart = $_POST['depart'],
                $return = $_POST['return'],
                $no_of_passengers = $_POST['no_of_passengers']
            );
            $data['search_result'] = $this->CrudModel->search_round_trip('flight', $flight_from, $flight_to, $depart, $return, $no_of_passengers);
            $this->session->tempdata($data['search_result']);
            $this->session->tempdata();
            $this->load->view('partials/header');
            $this->load->view('partials/nav');
            $this->load->view('result', $data);
        }
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_passengers', 'Number of Passengers', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->index();
        } else {
            $search_result = array(
                $flight_from = $_POST['flight_from'],
                $flight_to = $_POST['flight_to'],
                $depart = $_POST['depart'],
                $no_of_passengers = $_POST['no_of_passengers']
            );
            $data['search_result'] = $this->CrudModel->search_one_way('flight', $flight_from, $flight_to, $depart, $no_of_passengers);

            $this->load->view('partials/header');
            $this->load->view('partials/nav');
            $this->load->view('result', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean is, I will put everything the available flights into tempdata?

Comment: not the list of flights, your search parameters you have to store in tempdata.

Comment: The things that I've done is, as you said, in my search method I inserted $this->session->tempdata($data['search_result']); $this->session->tempdata();. Btw, I edited my post. I put my search method

Comment: Okay, Provide me one more information and I can help you out from this. You dont want to make search call again or you are getting an error while making search call again.?

Comment: I altered my answer please check.

Comment: It becomes a white page. I will insert it above of my if($flight == 'roundtrip')? right?

Comment: In both the case, see when you coming back from login page to search page,first you have to check data from `Tempdata`, if data available then assign. and this all logic will be right after method start okay.

Comment: Check, I have added your search function in my answer, Please modify as per your requirement.

Comment: still a blank or white page. And I think there's some misunderstanding, I am not in the login page. I am in the search page(User/search) then when I tried to select flight. there will be a prompt message then it will redirect you in the same page.. but the problem is, the results of the search is now  gone/null